# Posso usar dois insert into no mesmo comando

Tags: c#, mysql

eu tenho a seguinte linha de código e queria saber se é possível fazer dois select dentro de um único comando sql

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into FUNCIONARIO(`CPF_FUNCIONARIO`, `NOME_FUNCIONARIO`, `RG_FUNCIONARIO `, `ENDEREÇO_FUNCIONARIO`, `NUMERO_FUNCIONARIO`, `BAIRRO_FUNCIONARIO`, `CEP_FUNCIONARIO`, `CIDADE_FUNCIONARIO`, `ADMISSÃO_FUNCIONARIO`, `DEMISSÃO_FUNCIONARIO`, `ID_CARGO`, `AUMENTO_FUNCIONARIO`) values(@CPF,@NOME,@RG,@ENDERECO,@NUMERO,@BAIRRO,@CEP,@CIDADE,@CARGO,@AUMENTO)  INSERT INTO `LOGIN`(`USUARIO_LOGIN`, `SENHA_LOGIN`, `CPF_FUNCIONARIO`) VALUES (@LOGIN,@SENHA,@CPF)", con);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode sim, eu inclusive faço muito isso. além de separar os values com ",", você tem que ter exatamente a mesma quantidade de parâmetros de todas as sequências de values, ex:

```
insert into my_table (coluna1, coluna2,coluna3) 
            values   (@0,@1,@2),(@3,@4,@5),(@6,@7,@8)...;
```

Se em alguma sequência de values você colocar dois ou um parâmetro vai dar erro, tem que ser sempre 3 parâmetros porque eu defini 3 colunas.